# Find the $x$ and $y$ such that $23771x+19945y=1$ where $|x|$ and $|y|$ are as small as possible

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the smallest values of $x$ and $y$ such that $|x|$ and $|y|$ would be as small as possible.
>   $$23771x+19945y=1$$

Thank for all the help!  I assure you this is **not homework**!

Comment: People stop downvoting me this question is not even a homework question!

Comment: People are likely not downvoting you because they think this is a homework question. They are downvoting you because you have posted many questions in the past hour which have shown no thought or effort on your part, despite repeated requests from the community to show where you have gotten and what you are thinking. This is required from ALL questions, not just homework - people will just simply not help you with homework without effort on your part, whereas other questions may yet receive attention. If you adjust this, I assure you that your questions will be well received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  Apply the [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: What is the Euclidean Algorithm?

Comment: Here's an explanation: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/Euclid.shtml. The answerer has provided a link as well.

Comment: @CommanderShepard This video explains the algorithm beautifully: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwuj4yzoX1o&list=FL3oKQGoW_XPQfq1PCnHjXGw&index=3